# Phonegap build doesn't update Icon

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

On config.xml I have

```
<icon src="images.png" gap:role="default" />
```

and in the root folder I have the images.png file.
Still, I get the default phonegap Icon.
I have also tried

```
<icon src="icon.png" gap:role="default" />
```

and rename my file to icon.png , and it didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where do you see the default PhoneGap icon? Is it on the PhoneGap Build page or on the actual device as you have installed the app?

According to this [issue](https://github.com/phonegap/build/issues/138) this is a known bug that is still not fixed.

From this [link](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/app_build_page_icon_not_updating):

> As a temporary workaround please remove and re-create the app.

Comment: I see the Icon on my device.

Comment: remove and re-create the app on phonegap build solved the issue.

Comment: The same also for 2018